# Error in visual studio 2010 Application error(opencv 244)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I tried installing opencv 244 on visual studio 2010 (64 bit).After rectifying many missing dll problems, I am stuck with this problem

[image]

And i m getting the following errors in the output

```
'Panoroma_25.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Jango\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\projects_opencv\Panoroma_25\x64\Debug\Panoroma_25.exe', Symbols loaded.
'Panoroma_25.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Panoroma_25.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Panoroma_25.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Panoroma_25.exe': Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin\opencv_core244d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Panoroma_25.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp110d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
The program '[6876] Panoroma_25.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
```

Comment: Well, first off, you are trying to link **VC11** libraries of OpenCV in a **VC10** project; which is incorrect. Rectify this and check if the project works.

Comment: I'd start by making sure that image load *succeeded*. And fyi, the base error 0x7B is error 123, which is: "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Comment: HOw shall i rectify it @scap3y

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see with this much information; you are probably using OpenCV's prebuilt binaries. And probably they were built with vc11 compiler. So what you should do is download source code and compile it with your Visual Studio compiler.

You can follow this installation guide from the docs of OpenCV: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#installation-by-making-your-own-libraries-from-the-source-files